Java 8 Glassfish4 Netbeans7.4
Olá, tudo bem? Estou com uma aplicação, e ao mudar a o Postgres- postgresql-9.2.jar para Postgres- postgresql-9.3.jar estou recebendo erros no log do Glassfish. Estou usando Glassfish4, JDK8 E NetBeans7.4
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [SistemaCrea-ejbPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7298] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The mapping [viagem] from the embedded ID class [class br.org.creapi.entities.FiscalViagemPk] is an invalid mapping for this class. An embeddable class that is used with an embedded ID specification (attribute [pk] from the source [class br.org.creapi.entities.FiscalViagem]) can only contain basic mappings. Either remove the non basic mapping or change the embedded ID specification on the source to be embedded.
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:230)
... 53 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7298] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The mapping [viagem] from the embedded ID class [class br.org.creapi.entities.FiscalViagemPk] is an invalid mapping for this class. An embeddable class that is used with an embedded ID specification (attribute [pk] from the source [class br.org.creapi.entities.FiscalViagem]) can only contain basic mappings. Either remove the non basic mapping or change the embedded ID specification on the source to be embedded.
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.invalidMappingForEmbeddedId(ValidationException.java:1307)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.EmbeddedIdAccessor.addIdFieldsFromAccessors(EmbeddedIdAccessor.java:148)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.EmbeddedIdAccessor.process(EmbeddedIdAccessor.java
